# Uneven flow in ZMQ

Tags: java, message-queue, zeromq

I am using ZMQ in my Java application. I found that it behaves unevenly i.e if I send some 100 message with One consumer say it takes 1 sec then if we go on increasing the consumers the time taken becomes 2,1.5,3 such that. There is no gradual increase or decrease. How can I correct this. Look for my code below

```
// Broker
```

`import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;
import org.zeromq.ZMQStreamer;`

`public class Broker {`

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

    Socket frontEnd = context.socket(ZMQ.PULL);
    frontEnd.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    Socket backEnd = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);
    backEnd.bind("tcp://*:5560");

    ZMQStreamer zmqStreamer = new ZMQStreamer(context, frontEnd, backEnd);
    zmqStreamer.run();
}
```

}

`// Producer`

`import org.zeromq.ZMQ;`
`import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;`

`public class Producer` 
`{`

```
public void init()
{
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    socket = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
}

public void initMessage(String message)
{
    this.message = message;
}

public void sendMessage()
{
    String sendMessage = System.nanoTime() +"#"+ message;
    socket.send(sendMessage.getBytes(), 0);
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Producer producer = new Producer();
    producer.init();
    byte[] message = new byte[Integer.parseInt(args[0])];
    //message = "Hello".getBytes();
    producer.initMessage(new String(message));
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        producer.sendMessage();
    }
}

private Socket socket = null;
private String message;
}

//Consumer

import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;

public class Consumer 
{

public void init()
{
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    socket = context.socket(ZMQ.PULL);
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5560");
}

public void reciveMessage()
{
    byte[] recived = socket.recv(0);
    //System.out.println(recived.length);
    long recivedTime = System.nanoTime();
    String message = new String(recived);
    String[] splitMessage = message.split("#");
    long sendTime = Long.parseLong(splitMessage[0]);
    System.out.println("Send Time " + sendTime + " RecivedTime "
            + recivedTime + " Time taken " + (recivedTime - sendTime)
            + " Message " + message);
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
    consumer.init();
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        consumer.reciveMessage();
    }
}
private Socket socket = null;
}
```

Comment: Schildmeijer: I had attached the code. Kindly go through it.

Comment: i know this is not constructive, but the title of your question reminds me of Pearl Jam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reliably time a piece of multithreaded code, you're going to need to have some way of syncing the starting and ending times at the collector/sink (which you currently do not have shown to be programmed).

Check out [this example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer) from the ZMQ guide, which states the following process as one of the correct ZMQ ways of dividing a dataset:

> ...
>
> Our supercomputing application is a fairly typical parallel processing model:
>
> ```
> We have a ventilator that produces tasks that can be done in parallel.
> We have a set of workers that process tasks.
> We have a sink that collects results back from the worker processes.
> ```
>
> ...